# Cannot able to create Color resource in directory in android studio Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, resources

**My goal is to create state color resource**  
Cannot create a color resource under `res/` directory as `res/values/color.xml` already exists. While trying to create, not getting the color option!!

[image: Android resource directory creation]